# How to restrict anonymous FTP access to downloads only?

Tags: permissions, ftp, freebsd

I have a server running FreeBSD and have enabled anonymous FTP access, but wish to restrict the access to only being able to download files I have put on the server myself, because I don't want people putting unapproved things on it. Do I have to add something to a .conf file or enable/disable it in inetd? Or do I have to change permissions on something? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make the directory that anonymous users have access to unwritable by anyone except root.